# Composer require sonata-project/core-bundle in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, sonata, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I'd like to add **sonata-project/user-bundle** to Symfony 3.4 project but i received the following error message, BTW, i already installed  "**sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle**" :

```
composer require "sonata-project/user-bundle"
-------------------------------

Using version ^4.7 for sonata-project/user-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 4.7.0 conflicts with sonata-project/core-bundle[3.17.2].
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 4.7.0 conflicts with sonata-project/core-bundle[3.17.2].
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 4.7.0 conflicts with sonata-project/core-bundle[3.17.2].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle ^4.7 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[4.7.0].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/core-bundle (locked at 3.17.2) -> satisfiable by sonata-project/core-bundle[3.17.2].
```

For information, this the content of the **composer.json** file :

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.8",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    }
```

So what can i do please  ?

Comment: Just do a composer update, seems like you have a sonata already installed, versioning are a pain in a ass in symfony.

Comment: so let's see, symfony 3.4 sonata user-bundle 4.7 (which requires symfony 4.4+) I think the last user-bundle you can install is 4.5.3 https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle#4.5.3 please note that symfony 3.4 will not be supported forever and upgrading as probably advised ;o)

Comment: @Dezz H, I already did a composer update and I tried to add the sonata user-bundle dependency, but i had the same result.

Comment: @Jakumi  i did and this the following message :  Problem 1 : - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle 4.5.3 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[4.5.3]............................................. ,

Comment: Try `composer require "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" "sonata-project/user-bundle"`. It will update both bundles in one go.

Comment: @Leprechaun :                                                                                                            Problem 1
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.21.0 conflicts with sonata-project/core-bundle[3.17.2].